# Thread method not running?

Tags: java, multithreading

When I compile and run the StartThreads Class I get a list of integer 1 to 1000000 with false and at the end it prints true;
Now what I'm trying to find out is why does class threadone print nothing when it should print once the instance variable in class MyVariables = true?
    public class MyVariables {
        public boolean startApp = false;
    }

```
public class ThreadOne implements Runnable {
Thread t;
MyVariables x;
public ThreadOne(MyVariables x) {
    t = new Thread(this, "Thread One");
    this.x = x;
}   
@Override
public void run() {
    while(this.x.startApp != false) {
        System.out.println("Starting");
    }
}
public void start() {
    t.start();
}

}  

public class ThreadTwo implements Runnable {
Thread t;
MyVariables x;
public ThreadTwo(MyVariables x) {
    t = new Thread(this, "Thread One");
    this.x = x;
}   
@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized(this.x) {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 1000001; i++) {
            if(i == 1000001) {
                this.x.startApp = true;
                System.out.println(this.x.startApp);

            }
            else {
                System.out.println(this.x.startApp);
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

}
public void start() {
    t.start();
}

}


public class StartThreads {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyVariables a = new MyVariables();
    ThreadOne x = new ThreadOne(a);
    ThreadTwo y = new ThreadTwo(a);
    x.start();
    y.start();
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why should ThreadOne behave as you're stating? It's while loop is never run but rather is skipped over since the condition is not true. I think that you're expecting it to wait for something to change to true, but it does nothing of the sort, and instead once it sees that a condition is false, finishes execution.

Note that this is ugly code:

```
while(this.x.startApp != false) {
```

Why state while something is **not false**? That's the same as being **true**.
Better

```
while (x.startApp) {
```

Now as for your actual problem, perhaps you should instead make your while loop:

```
while (!x.startApp) {
  Thread.sleep(1);  // surrounded with try/catch
}
System.out.println("Starting");
```

e.g.,

```
class ThreadOne implements Runnable {
   Thread t;
   volatile MyVariables x;

   public ThreadOne(MyVariables x) {
      t = new Thread(this, "Thread One");
      this.x = x;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      while (!x.startApp) {
         try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Starting");
   }

   public void start() {
      t.start();
   }

}

class ThreadTwo implements Runnable {
   private static final int MAX_I = 10001;
   Thread t;
   volatile MyVariables x;

   public ThreadTwo(MyVariables x) {
      t = new Thread(this, "Thread One");
      this.x = x;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      synchronized (this.x) {
         for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_I; i++) {
            if (i == MAX_I) {
               this.x.startApp = true;
               System.out.println(this.x.startApp);

            } else {
               System.out.println(this.x.startApp);
               System.out.println(i);
            }
         }
      }

   }

   public void start() {
      t.start();
   }

}

public class StartThreads {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyVariables a = new MyVariables();
      ThreadOne x = new ThreadOne(a);
      ThreadTwo y = new ThreadTwo(a);
      x.start();
      y.start();
   }

}

class MyVariables {
   public volatile boolean startApp = false;
}
```

Also, I think that your boolean field should at the least be volatile.

---

Another way using a PropertyChangeListener and the observer pattern:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class StartThreads2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final MyVariables2 myVars2 = new MyVariables2();
      final RunOne runOne = new RunOne();
      final RunTwo runTwo = new RunTwo(myVars2);

      myVars2.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
            if (MyVariables2.START_APP.equals(pcEvt.getPropertyName())) {
               if (pcEvt.getNewValue().equals(Boolean.TRUE)) {
                  new Thread(runOne).start();
               }
            }
         }
      });

      new Thread(runTwo).start();
   }
}

class MyVariables2 {
   public static final String START_APP = "start app";
   private volatile boolean startApp = false;
   private PropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

   public boolean isStartApp() {
      return startApp;
   }

   public void setStartApp(boolean startApp) {
      boolean oldValue = this.startApp;
      boolean newValue = startApp;
      this.startApp = startApp;
      pcSupport.firePropertyChange(START_APP, oldValue, newValue);
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      pcSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }
}

class RunOne implements Runnable {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Starting RunOne");
   }
}

class RunTwo implements Runnable {
   private static final int MAX_I = 10001;
   private MyVariables2 myVars2;

   public RunTwo(MyVariables2 myVars2) {
      this.myVars2 = myVars2;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_I; i++) {
         System.out.println("startApp: " + myVars2.isStartApp());
         System.out.printf("i: %05d%n", i);
      }

      myVars2.setStartApp(true);      
      try {
         Thread.sleep(10);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      System.out.println("startApp: " + myVars2.isStartApp());
   }
}
```

Comment: if I change the while statment to "if(!this.x.startApp)" it still doesn't display so I don't know if the thread is working or not?

Comment: The while loop never "exits". How can it exit when it is never entered? It checks the condition before it runs the body and the condition is false like you said, but it is never entered so it can't exit. I'd understand if it was a do-while. Also, it'd be best if you mentioned to him that this.x.startApp needs to be set to true for his while loop to run. That's the only thing wrong with OP's code really. Other than that, there is no reason to synchronize in this case.

Comment: @JohnArckai: also, don't forget to use volatile variables, especially your boolean.

Comment: startApp should be volatile, or should be an AtomicBoolean, to make sure that all threads see that its value has changed. And instead of using a busy loop to check when to start, you'd better use a CountDownLatch, which is designed for that. Also, ignoring an InterruptedException is a bad idea. The thread should stop running ASAP if it's interrupted.

Comment: @JBNizet +1, but I would go a step further and claim that having a thread start just to wait for a condition should be replaced with having the thread start *at the point the condition is set to true*, and remove the whole coordination shebang.

Comment: Agree. Better to use an observer pattern which will trigger the next thread to start.

Comment: Nothing to add except +1 :)